# how to interpret mecab unidic csv columns

Tags: mecab

Here are some sample entries from mecab unidic:

> ネコ    - 名詞,普通名詞,一般,,,,ネコ,猫,ネコ,ネコ,ネコ,ネコ,和,,,,,,,体,ネコ,ネコ,ネコ,ネコ,1,C4,,7918141644612096,28806

> が - 助詞,格助詞,,,,,ガ,が,が,ガ,が,ガ,和,,,,,,,格助,ガ,ガ,ガ,ガ,,動詞%F2@0,名詞%F1,,2168520431510016,7889

> 蚊 - 名詞,普通名詞,一般,,,,カ,蚊,蚊,カ,蚊,カ,和,,,,,,,体,カ,カ,カ,カ,0,C4,,1536851034907136,5591

> を - 助詞,格助詞,,,,,ヲ,を,を,オ,を,オ,和,,,,,,,格助,ヲ,ヲ,ヲ,ヲ,,動詞%F2@0,名詞%F1,形容詞%F2@-1,,11381878116459008,41407

As you can see, there are 30 csv columns in those unidic entries. What do they all represent?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://towardsdatascience.com/mecab-usage-and-add-user-dictionary-to-mecab-9ee58966fc6 or google translate will give you a hint.

Comment: This tweet is perfect!  https://twitter.com/zakki/status/920977351059554304

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a list of the Japanese names of all columns at the [UniDic FAQ](https://clrd.ninjal.ac.jp/unidic/faq.html). Most of the columns are pretty obvious once you see the name.

There are more details in the [UniDic Manual](https://clrd.ninjal.ac.jp/unidic/UNIDIC_manual.pdf) that explain all the fields, though for some of them - mainly the `*ConType` and `*ModType` fields - they're pretty complicated. These fields are mostly related to the pronunciation of compound words.